# Expansion of $\log |1+x|$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I know that the absolute value function is not differentiable near $0$, but my question is : do we still have a Taylor expansion near $x=0$ of the following function : $x\mapsto \log |1+x|$ ?

Comment: Near $x=0$, $1+x>0$, so you could take off the abs function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may see the derivative gives.

$$x\mapsto (\log |1+x|)'=\frac{1}{1+x}~~x\in\Bbb R\setminus\{-1\}$$

you can apply Taylor expansion as well. for $|x|<1.$

Answer (score 1):

For this function, $x=0$ is an ordinary point, as $|x+1|$ is differentiable there. The trouble is with $x=-1$.